# How can I set the text on my matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to do a figure using matplotlib. Here is my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import matplotlib.image as mpimg


Figure = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 3))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)
ax = Figure.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax.axis('off')
img=mpimg.imread('test.jpg')
ax.imshow(img)
ax1 = Figure.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
ax1.axis('off')
ax1.text(0, 0, "Test", color="white", style='oblique',     ha='left', wrap=True,
         bbox={'facecolor': "#34C8EC",'boxstyle': 'round,pad=1'})
plt.show()
```

I got this :

[image]

And I would like to have something like this :

[image]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The first two arguments in ax1.text() are setting the position to (0,0).

You need to change those values in order to change the position of the text.

Note that you are currently using data coordinates. In order to use axis coordinates, you need to provide the optional argument transform=ax.transAxes. More info in here: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html

They actually provide an example of a text in the centre of the image. It would be:

```
ax1.text(0.5, 0.5, 'matplotlib', horizontalalignment='center',
         verticalalignment='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
```